How can I change the " - Shortcut" suffix on shortcuts in Explorer Win11
Now shortcuts has " - Shortcut" as a suffix.
I'd like to change it. I'd also like to put it in front.

To change this behavior requires registry update.
Below are the contents for two .reg files:
disable - Shortcut text.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"link"=hex:00,00,00,00

restore - Shortcut text.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"link"=hex:1E,00,00,00

Copy these contents to a .reg, save it, then double-click it
to update the registry, agreeing to all the intermediate warnings.
I tried it and it works to eliminate the - Shortcut part.
However, I don't know of a way to put this text in front.
Source :
How-to: Windows 10 registry - user interface settings.

Thanks, but I think this just removes it.

Yes, as I said - it eliminates it. I didn't encounter any method for modifying this action, it's either on or off.

I searched the registry for the " - Shortcut" string, but it didn't work. Maybe it's encoded to hex?

It's most likely built-in into Explorer.

Yes, the language pack maybe, because you can change it by language.

My (freshly installed) Windows 11 23H2 shows link    REG_BINARY    1B000000 (not 1E000000) in response to reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer -v link

Use this value in restore - Shortcut text.reg instead of the one in my answer. It contains your personal settings.
